# How to properly install mlflow in R using docker?

Tags: r, devops, mlflow

Is there any standard image or step to install mlflow and R in docker?

Whenever I do, sometimes its *CURL not found issue*, *dependencies are not installed properly*...
https://mdneuzerling.com/post/deploying-r-models-with-mlflow-and-docker/
Followed this and it failed.

```
Warning messages:
1: In install.packages("mlflow", dependencies = TRUE) :
  installation of package ‘curl’ had non-zero exit status
2: In install.packages("mlflow", dependencies = TRUE) :
  installation of package ‘RCurl’ had non-zero exit status
3: In install.packages("mlflow", dependencies = TRUE) :
  installation of package ‘httr’ had non-zero exit status
4: In install.packages("mlflow", dependencies = TRUE) :
  installation of package ‘h2o’ had non-zero exit status
5: In install.packages("mlflow", dependencies = TRUE) :
  installation of package ‘covr’ had non-zero exit status
6: In install.packages("mlflow", dependencies = TRUE) :
  installation of package ‘sparklyr’ had non-zero exit status
7: In install.packages("mlflow", dependencies = TRUE) :
  installation of package ‘mlflow’ had non-zero exit status
```

Comment: Depending on which OS you're using within the Docker image, corresponding system dependencies should be installed. OpenSSL, CURL and possibly other packages rely on some -dev/-devel version of packages that do not come preinstalled. It's hard to say what went wrong without a (more) complete error trace.

Comment: I feel there is not much support of MLFLOW for R.
I was hoping to get a standard process to install mlflow for R.
Multiple errors, even after installing these packages through ubuntu, it still says the same error

Answer (score 2):

There's an R API: https://mlflow.org/docs/latest/R-api.html#r-api.
For a very basic set up You can use this Dockerfile:

```
FROM rocker/tidyverse

# Install python
RUN apt-get update -qq && \
 apt-get install -y python3-pip tcl tk libz-dev libpng-dev

RUN ln -f /usr/bin/python3 /usr/bin/python
RUN ln -f /usr/bin/pip3 /usr/bin/pip
RUN pip install -U pip

# Install mlflow
RUN pip install mlflow

# Create link for python
RUN ln -f /usr/bin/python3 /usr/bin/python

# Install additional R packages
RUN R -e "devtools::install_github('mlflow/mlflow', subdir = 'mlflow/R/mlflow')"
RUN R -e "install.packages(c('carrier'))" # for crating
# any other packages Your R project requires
# RUN R -e "install.packages(...)"
```

In an R script:

```
library(mlflow)

# ... some R code

with(run <- mlflow_start_run(), {
  print("building model...\n")
  ctrl <- rpart.control(cp = 0.1)
  model <- rpart(Species ~ ., data = iris, method = "class", control = ctrl)

  predictor <- crate(~ stats::predict(!!model, .x, type = "class"))
  predicted <- predictor(iris)

  print("logging model...\n")
  mlflow_log_model(predictor, "model")
})
```

This is only a draft. The link You provided is a more real-life scenario. Treat my answer as a toy, but maybe it can help You diving into more complex problems. I think You'll need to know something more than basics about Docker and Linux to make R and mlflow working together in a container. The errors You get are most likely related to missing packages in the system (in Docker). Pay attention on Your base image.

Hope it helps somewhat.

Comment: Thank you very much for your answer. Although I am not working on it now, I will definitely try it out.